# Django: Get an attribute (imagefield) from a Foreign Key's reverse relation object

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've been struggling with the right syntax for this. I want to create a gallery of photo albums, and have a selectable cover photo for each album. But to do this, I need to grab the reverse relation object and then choose the imagefield attribute from it. I know how to use the relation manager to filter the cover photo object (based on a cover boolean attribute) but not how to then get the imagefield attribute from that object (to then reference in the template for img src).
Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
    
def make_pic_path (instance, filename):
        albname = instance.album.name
    path = 'AlbPics/{0}/{1}'.format(albname, filename)
    return path

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    dates = models.CharField(max_length = 100) 
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    
    def cover_photo (self):
        return self.albumpicture_set.filter(cover = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name    

class AlbumPicture(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to = make_pic_path, blank = True)
    picture_desc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cover = models.BooleanField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.picture_desc
```

and the views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Album, AlbumPicture
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def alb_gallery(request):
    gallery = Album.objects.all()
    context = {'gallery': gallery, }
    return render(request, 'gallery/gallery.html', context)
```

And the template gallery.html (or my best guess)

```
{% if gallery %}
    <ul>
        {% for entry in gallery %}
            <ul>
                <li> {{entry.name}} </li>
                <li><img src= "{{entry.cover_photo.url}}"> {{entry.name}}</li>
            </ul>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

I think ideally I'd like to have a method inside the Album model that will return the imagefield attribute needed for the cover photo. It seems simple enough but I can't quite figure it out!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How do you want to handle Albums with multiple cover photos or no cover photos? A simple solution could be to add a ForeignKey from Album to AlbumPicture for the cover photo

Comment: I'm honestly not there yet.... I wanted to figure this out first and then close up those holes. But let's say if there's no cover photo, no photo is shown.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the combined suggestions of Biplove and iklinac, I've figured out how to do this!

The method under the Album model is:

```
def cover_photo (self):
    cov = self.adventurepicture_set.get(cover = True)
    return cov.picture
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, cover photo will not be more than one (I suppose?).  Thanks to @iklinac for pointing out `filter` is not correct when expecting single object. As answer is already given by @Sara. I would still like to propose nice way to handle empty cases.

```
class Album(models.Model):
    ....

    def cover_photo (self):
        obj = {}
        try:
            obj = (self.albumpicture_set.get(cover = True)).picture
        except:
            # The cover photo is empty then show default cover pic
            obj.url = "default_cover.jpg" 
        return obj
```

Comment: I've tried this and I get the following error: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'picture'

Comment: filter will always return QuerySet

Comment: I changed it to .get and it worked! Thanks for the tip!!

Comment: @iklinac in case of only one result, does `filter` and `get` still differs?

Comment: yes as documented https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get

Comment: in the case of using filter:  ```obj = self.albumpicture_set.filter(cover = True)``` would ```obj[0]``` refer to the actual object?

Comment: yes, only difference at the end would be case of different exception handling